# How to fix "repaints on scroll" performance issue?

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs5

In my app I have a grid which is populated with at least 30 rows.
When running sencha app inspector in chrome it tells me that this grid "repaints on scroll" and, indeed, it lags a little on chrome, while in ie my app almost freezes.

How to fix this?

edit: 
This is my gridpanel

```
Ext.define('tabInfo', {
extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',

constructor: function(config){
      //performing some initialization, like defining columns, store, etc.
   this.superclass.constructor.call(this, {
        id: 'gridInfo',
        store: store,   
        selModel: checkboxModel, 
        columns: columnsArray,
        columnLines: true,
        frame: true,
        bbar: Ext.create('Ext.PagingToolbar', {
            store: store,
            displayInfo: true,
            displayMsg: 'Displaying topics {0} - {1} of {2}',
            emptyMsg: "No topics to display"
        }),
        tbar : topBar
    });

    //this is for performances: I first load items into the store and then
    //resume layout to render all changes
    Ext.suspendLayouts();
    store.load({
        params:{
            start: 0,
            limit: itemsPerPage
        }
    });
    Ext.resumeLayouts(true);
```

Comment: Can you share your grid config please

Comment: Done, tell me if you need some other information!

Comment: Ok, I dont understand why there is a need to suspend and resume layouts whilst you are waiting for the load. Also, you should really be resuming layouts in either a call back configured in your store.load() or in a load listener. The way you have coded it wont necessarily mean the load has completed by the time resumeLayouts gets called.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks for the tip! Nevertheless, the performance issue I am writing this topic for is not due to this so this still doesn't answer to my question ://

Comment: In IE, does the freeze behaviour recover so you can carry on using the grid?

Comment: Yes it does, but on each scroll it freezes for a sec or so making my app so laggy it can't be used. I think chrome has a better javascript engine so it can live with that, anyway the app is still laggy (but less than on ie). For these reasons I'd like to fix the problem.

Comment: Did you try using the bufferedrenderer plugin on your grid?

Comment: Added now but it tells me: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetHeight' of undefined" at extjs-all.js line 22

Comment: All of this may depend on how many columns/rows you have, what the column renderers are doing (if you have them doing custom logic), etc.